# Is a muscle still a muscle after years without usage?

Tags: muscle, nerves, muscular-atrophy, muscular-dystrophy

With no usage I mean no active usage because of not working nerves.

So basically the question is wether there is like an end-state to muscle atropy where the muscle tissue changes and after what time this state is reached.

Comment: Ehh might be a better question for bio.stackexchange

Comment: seems like it, how could it be moved?

Comment: I flagged it for mods, hope you get an answer! :)

Comment: Sorry, but this is too old to migrate. The core question about the end state of atrophy is interesting, I would expand and clarify a bit and post it on biology.